# Assembly: Generating multiple random ints with MIPS?

Tags: assembly, random, int, character, mips

So I'm trying to figure out how to generate a string of 10 different, random integer characters using the get system time syscall, but the output always results in a 10-digit string of the same character (e.g. "mmmmmmmmmm") rather than a 10-digit string of random characters (e.g. "SdgeuEOufm").

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!

```
    .data:
        string: .space 11
        upper: .word 0
        lower: .word 0
    .text:
        la $t0, string  
        li $t1, 0   
        la $t2, upper
        la $t3, lower
    main:
        li $v0, 30
        syscall            
        li $v0, 40
        syscall           
        li $a1, 58
        li $v0, 42
        syscall          
        addi $a0, $a0, 65     
        sb $a0, ($t0)   

        addi $t0, $t0, 1    
        addi $t1, $t1, 1    
        blt $t1, 10, main
        sb $zero, 0($t0)    

        la $a0, string
        li $v0, 4
        syscall
```

Comment: I'm assuming MARS simulator?

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at some of the system calls you're using in your loop:

```
li $v0, 30
syscall            
li $v0, 40
syscall
```

> MARS system call 30 - time (system time) (as milliseconds since 1 January 1970)
>   `$a0` = low order 32 bits of system time
>   **`$a1` = high order 32 bits of system time.**

> MARS system call 40 - set seed
>   `$a0` = i.d. of pseudorandom number generator (any int).
>   **`$a1` = seed for corresponding pseudorandom number generator.**

In other words, you're using the high 32 bits of the millisecond count to seed the PRNG in every iteration of the loop. Unless your loop iterations take an extremely long time that will give you the same seed in every iteration, which will result in the same output from the PRNG in every iteration.
My suggestion is to only seed the PRNG once (before the loop starts) and to use the low 32 bits of the system time instead of the high bits.